# Экранирование HTML-кода, кроме разрывов строк

Tags: php, javascript, html

У меня на сайте есть много полей с помощью которых можно записать текст в базу данных. Так вот, чтобы пользователи не записали какой нибудь скрипт используется `htmlspecialchars`. Но `htmlspecialchars` также выводит `<br>` как текст. А нужно чтобы `<br>` и другие виды разрыва (Например `\n`) работали, а не выводились как текст.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После использование `htmlspecialchars()` можно одной заменой `&lt;br&gt;` на `<br>` вернуть, или делать другую замену:

```
strtr($txt, array('&' => '&amp;', '<' => '&lt;', '>' => '&gt;', "\n" => '<br>') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Для преобразования переводов строк в 
 можно воспользоваться функцией `nl2br()`

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
```

Если ваша задача сохранить тэги `<br />`, то их можно заменить перед вызовом `htmlspecialchars()` на какую-нибудь уникальную последовательность, например `[br]`, а после вызова `htmlspecialchars()`, осуществить обратное преобразование в `<br />`.

Кроме того, если вы хотите полностью исключить тэги из текста, можно воспользоваться функцией `strip_tags()`, которая вторым параметром позволяет задать список тэгов, которые необходимо оставить в тексте

```
strip_tags($text, '<br><br/>');
```

Comment: strip_tags не подошел. Он удалял теги с содержимым. Например удалил ссылку(с текстом ссылки)